# bash shell program does not show ascii value

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ascii

I am trying to input a character from the user and display the corresponding ascii value to the screen.
This is my code. If there are any errors please rectify and post it.

```
echo Enter a character
read n
printf "%d" $n;
```

Error-: ./ascii.sh: line 3: printf: a: invalid number

Comment: The answer is hidden [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a single quote before `$n`:

```
echo Enter a character
read n
printf "%d" \'$n
```

You can also get rid of the `echo`:

```
read -p 'Enter a character: ' n
printf "%d" \'$n
```

Comment: Could you explain why you put a single quote and escaped it?

Comment: From the POSIX spec (linked by @devnull): "If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote." The escaped quote is necessary to prevent the shell from processing it as the beginning of a quoted string. `printf "%d" "'$n"` would work as well.

Comment: +1 for posting this answer before I posted my mistaken explanation of why this wasn't possible :)